# upload via git: fatal: '/git/p/Boggle' does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: python, git, boggle

I am doing the reddit pygame boggle challenge.  On my laptop it is in a directory called Boggler, but at sourceforge it is called pygame-boggle.  When I do 'git push -u origin master' it gives the error in the title.  What am I doing wrong?  How do I get it to push?

I followed the instructions here: https://sourceforge.net/p/pygame-boggle/code/ref/master/

Comment: Can you add the error you get to the question?

Comment: I get the error in the title: fatal:  '/git/p/Boggle' does not appear to be a git repository

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialized the repo? It seems like you haven't.

Run the command `git init` to set up a git repo. Then, add a remote to your repo (wherever it may be, github or bitbucket or any other site) by running the command

`git remote add <url to remote here>`